# ffmpeg использования ресурсов GPU Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Можно использовать moviepy или pypi(ffmpeg) за счёт ресурсов видео карты в python?
Сейчас я использую moviepy и "рендер" идёт за счёт процессора что сильно нагружает пк.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А как вы используете **ffmpeg**? если вызывая внешний исполняемый фойл то надо просто добавить нужные ключи для использования **CUDA**, т.е. ***-vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid***, но кодирование на GPU даёт менее качественную картинку при равном размере файла.
Подробная инструкция [тут](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide/), в кртце **ffmpeg** должен быть собран с флагами
*--enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp*

Comment: использовал moviepy, сейчас посмотрел документацию ffmpeg для python и указал параметр для nvidia. Результатом я доволен скорость в разы выше, если на moviepy примерно 1к1 по длительности видео рендер шел, то здесь х20. Использую только 1 параметр.
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, "new_video/new_"+a, vcodec = 'h264_nvenc')

Comment: Только не совсем понятно куда прописывать ключи для этой библиотеки, например если я хочу убрать первые N секунд видео.

Comment: Читайте документацию, или если там можно передать ключи то это можно делать с помощью ключей ffmpeg, -ss, -sseof и т.д. Лучше смотите в документации на ffmpeg https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html